# Download a file in django with a button using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, python, django, download

I looked at many same questions but none resolved my problem,
I'm trying to download a file generated in my view using a button.
Problem : I get an empty file while clicking on download button

My view:

```
class dumpView(View):

template_name = 'download.html'
def get(self, request):
    file = open("/home/test.pdf", "rwbt")
    response = HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename=%s' % file
    return render(request, 'download.html')
```

My url:

```
url(r'^dump/', dumpView.as_view()),
```

My template:

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %} 
 {% load staticfiles %} 
 {% block content %}
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <center>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dump">Download</a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %} 
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{% static 'js/home.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My Django view is rendering the response. I did add an on click handler to the button with class dump in the UI to make a XHR request to the “/dump” URL  and recieve response as a blob and download the file with custom name and date.

My js :

```
$(".dump").on("click", function() {
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var a, today;
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
        today = new Date();
        a.download = "file_" + today.toDateString().split(" ").join("_") + ".pdf";
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        return a.click();
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/dump", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
xhttp.send();
});
```

Comment: How are you using 'response' var in view?

Comment: I don't return response so that i can use my template. If i just make "return response" i can download the file directly without having my template so my button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your view, I suggest adding a size to your response

```
content = file(filename).read()
response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'my_pdf.pdf'
```

As @bob-vork just said, the filename from `Content-Disposition` should not be the python `file` object, but the name your download will have.

How about registering the view in urls.py then replace the javascript by:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.open('download_my_pdf')">
```

EDIT :

Since you're going with the suggested HTML, then I'll put more details to my solution.

First, you can drop the `home.js`. As you understood

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dump">Download</a>
```

becomes

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.open('download_my_pdf')">
```

your `views.py` should return directly the `response`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

@login_required
def download_pdf(request):
    filename = 'whatever_in_absolute_path__or_not.pdf'
    content = FileWrapper(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'whatever_name_will_appear_in_download.pdf'
    return response
```

Pay attention to put the right content_type as well. Note that I haven't tested the view (especially the FileWrapper), I adapted some code I had for plain text. This is also why you have a TypeError if you treat the pdf as a text file.

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = (
    [...]
    url('download_my_pdf', download_pdf),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i did replaced javascript with what u suggested and the url as : "url(r'^dump/', dumpView.as_view(), name='download_my_pdf')", i can't download the file while pressing the button.

Comment: and when i use content and getsize() as you've right, i'm getting a TypeError " coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found"

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you set `Content-Disposition` as `attachment; filename=...` but you append the file object. My guess is the browser might want a filename, preferably with the right extension.

I have a similar view in a Django project, and I'm quoting the filename as well, but I'm not sure if that is necessary

EDIT: also, there is a typo in "attachment", remove the extra "e" and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that doesn't resolve the problem, i tried this : "response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename=%s' % test.pdf" and also "response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement; filename=%s' % /home/test.pdf" but i've got an empty file.

Comment: P.s : i think that my js doesn't receive response from the view because when i did try return response i can download the file successfully without template or button